# Is Google Cloud Function Trigger from PubSub Topic a Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got two environments in GCC with similar setups. Cloud functions triggered by PubSub Topics. In both the cloud functions list the PubSub topic as the trigger.

In one environment the Topic lists a subscription count of 1 which is listed as a Push to endpoint with a url of https://guid-dot-uid-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/name/topics/topic_name?pubsub_trigger=true

In the other environment the subscription count is 0. So I'm confused as to whether this push to endpoint url subscription is related to the cloud function trigger or is it just something I've accidentally set up somewhere along the way and is not actually doing anything? (I'd delete the subscription to find out, but it's actually in a live environment and I don't want to inadvertently break it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Google Cloud Function that is triggered on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, than the topic has a  subscription. The push to endpoint url subscription that you posted

> https://guid-dot-uid-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/name/topics/topic_name?pubsub_trigger=true

is indeed a trigger for one of your Cloud Functions.

Comment: Indeed, as I check again both environments have the same subscription count of 1 and similar subscription endpoint urls. But I promise when I asked the question the console was definitely reporting a count of zero on one of them and I haven't changed anything... I will put it down to gremlins!